# Specify command path with dragonfly gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, dragonfly-gem

I keep getting an error when i try to upload an Image with dragonfly. I know what the problem is because I solved it when I was using paperclip. But I don't know how to solve it for dragonfly.

The problem is that dragonfly is executing the command "identify" and it's looking for the binary on "/usr/local" but instead it's on "/opt/local" in Paperclip, I would easily solve this with.

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/opt/local/bin/"
```

Anyone knows the equivalent command for dragonfly? I'm using rails 3 btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, but going into the file: image_magick_utils.rb and changing:

```
  configurable_attr :convert_command, "convert"
  configurable_attr :identify_command, "identify"
```

to:

```
  configurable_attr :convert_command, "/opt/local/bin/convert"
  configurable_attr :identify_command, "/opt/local/bin/identify"
```

Comment: This answer also works, and is more compatible with dev / production environment duality: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355846/refinerycms-image-not-loading-dragonfly-error