# Rails 3 and RefineryCMS - Dragonfly::Shell::CommandFailed in Refinery::Admin::ImagesController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, refinerycms, dragonfly-gem

Looks like multiple people have this same/similar issues and there are a couple of reported fixes for it that I've found on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355846/refinerycms-image-not-loading-dragonfly-error) .  Unfortunately, they are not working for me.  I'm running MacOS Lion.  Here is what I've done so far:

1) Standard RefineryCMS install.  Runs well except for uploading images.
2) Once I encounter the problem, I added a configuration file per the Dragonfly [docs](http://markevans.github.com/dragonfly/file.Rails3.html):

```
# configure/initializers/dragonfly.rb
require 'dragonfly/rails/images'
```

3) That didn't work.  I reinstalled ImageMagick. Confirmed ImageMagick is installed:

```
# whereis convert
/usr/bin/convert
# whereis identify
/usr/bin/identify
```

4) That didn't fix things, so I set up symbolic links for /usr/bin and /usr/local/bin:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  22 Aug  4 11:00 /usr/bin/convert -> /opt/local/bin/convert
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  23 Aug  4 11:01 /usr/bin/identify -> /opt/local/bin/identify
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  22 Aug  4 11:06 /usr/local/bin/convert -> /opt/local/bin/convert
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  23 Aug  4 11:07 /usr/local/bin/identify -> /opt/local/bin/identify
```

5) That didn't work so I set up a new config file per the Dragonfly docs and some additional [instructions](http://markevans.github.com/dragonfly/file.ImageMagick.html#Configuration):

```
# config/initializers/dragonfly.rb
require 'dragonfly'

app = Dragonfly[:images]
app.configure_with(:imagemagick)
app.configure_with(:rails)

app.define_macro(ActiveRecord::Base, :image_accessor)

app.configure do |c|
  c.convert_command = "/opt/local/bin/convert"          # defaults to "convert"
  c.identify_command = "/opt/local/bin/identify"        # defaults to "identify"
  c.log_commands = true                                 # defaults to false
end
```

6) That did not fix it.  Based on a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/resolve/refinerycms/issues/1781) I added this

```
# config/application.rb
module Refincmstest
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # trying a fix for image magic
    initializer 'override-image-magick-paths', :after => 'attach-refinery-images-with-dragonfly' do
      Dragonfly[:refinery_images].configure do |c|
        c.convert_command = "/opt/local/bin/convert"          # defaults to "convert"
        c.identify_command = "/opt/local/bin/identify"        # defaults to "identify"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And that that did not work.  Here is the console output, if this helps:

```
Started POST "/refinery/images?dialog=true" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-04 12:23:54 -0700
Processing by Refinery::Admin::ImagesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Nddc/uPbbAGevNH15M6nzo/AJmVskIClJYZ5O60KDTU=", "image"=>{"image"=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fe5cd383e10 @original_filename="Photo on 2010-10-27 at 22.46 #2.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image[image][]\"; filename=\"Photo on 2010-10-27 at 22.46 #2.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/rr/1_vvbrvd3ylgpdv8f2z3qqp80000gn/T/RackMultipart20120804-97351-xbv8ew>>]}, "wymeditor"=>"", "modal"=>"true", "dialog"=>"true", "app_dialog"=>"true", "field"=>"", "update_image"=>"", "thumbnail"=>"", "callback"=>"", "conditions"=>"", "locale"=>:en}
  Refinery::Role Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "refinery_roles".* FROM "refinery_roles" WHERE "refinery_roles"."title" = 'Refinery' LIMIT 1
  Refinery::User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "refinery_users".* FROM "refinery_users" INNER JOIN "refinery_roles_users" ON "refinery_users"."id" = "refinery_roles_users"."user_id" WHERE "refinery_roles_users"."role_id" = 1
  Refinery::User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "refinery_users".* FROM "refinery_users" WHERE "refinery_users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Refinery::UserPlugin Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "refinery_user_plugins".* FROM "refinery_user_plugins" WHERE "refinery_user_plugins"."user_id" = 1 ORDER BY position ASC
  Refinery::Role Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "refinery_roles".* FROM "refinery_roles" INNER JOIN "refinery_roles_users" ON "refinery_roles"."id" = "refinery_roles_users"."role_id" WHERE "refinery_roles_users"."user_id" = 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 210ms

Dragonfly::Shell::CommandFailed (Command failed (identify '/var/folders/rr/1_vvbrvd3ylgpdv8f2z3qqp80000gn/T/RackMultipart20120804-97351-xbv8ew') with exit status ):
  dragonfly (0.9.12) lib/dragonfly/shell.rb:29:in `raise_shell_command_failed'
  dragonfly (0.9.12) lib/dragonfly/shell.rb:23:in `run'
  ...
```

I'm out of ideas.  Any suggestions on where to go next?

Comment: This url is helpful for this issue.
http://superuser.com/questions/163818/how-to-install-rmagick-on-ubuntu-10-04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some more researching and found that although I had used Mac Ports to update ImageMagick, my installation was somehow corrupt.  I found this by trying to execute the `/opt/local/bin/identify` command manually.  Multiple attempts to reinstall with Map Ports failed (Mac Ports has some very serious problems running on a mac book air running lion.)  I installed Mac Brew and and installed ImageMagick via brew.  After removing my symbolic links and ensuring that dragonfly was configured to point to /usr/local/bin everything worked.

Moral of the story - Don't use Mac Ports if you are on a MacBook Air running Lion.  The install of multiple ImageMagick prerequisites fail even after reinstalling Mac Ports with the latest version.  Similar thing happened to me a few months ago with another Mac Ports install.  Had to temporarily retro back a previous version of the Mac dev tools. Such a pain.

Comment: Can you give some more details or resources for doing this? I ditched macports and reinstalled imagemagick but don't know how to point dragonfly to the right location.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error after upgrading to **OS X Yosemite**. 
Since I installed imagemagick with brew I run `brew doctor` and it reported various problems and, among them, a symlink problem too. I followed the instructions to solve all the problems and now it's working again.